# Download image code in php

Tags: php, image, curl

I am a newbie to php and wish to write a code for download that allows users to download image. Meaning i have given a download link onclick of whick the image located on the server should start downloading. i have tried various options like fopen, curl etc. but to no avail. on using curl the image downloads but does not open up in the place where it gets downloaded. It gives error saying "Cant read file header! unknown file format." Please help here's the curl code i used :

```
function DownloadImageFromUrl($imagepath)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $imagepath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$imagecontent =DownloadImageFromUrl("http://www.xyz.com/back_img.png");
$savefile = fopen('myimage.png', 'w');
fwrite($savefile, $imagecontent);
fclose($savefile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use http headers for this

```
header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
exit($data);
```

mime - MIME type of image

filename - Name of downloading file

data - the file. You can get image from other server using for example this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.xyz.com/back_img.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$imagecontent =DownloadImageFromUrl("http://www.xyz.com/back_img.png");
$savefile = fopen('myimage.png', 'r');
fread($savefile, $imagecontent);
fclose($savefile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadFile ($url, $path) {

  $newfname = $path;
  $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
  if ($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

    if ($newf)
    while(!feof($file)) {
      fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
    }
  }

  if ($file) {
    fclose($file);
  }

  if ($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
  }
 }

downloadFile ("http://www.site.com/image.jpg", "images/name.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `header()` method to make it open as a downloadable item.

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
```

where

`$fullPath` is the image path.

For more specification refer to - [header in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple class: [imagedownloaderphp](https://github.com/adminazhar/imagedownloaderphp)

Just replace the url and directory, example:

```php
require "ImageDownload.php";
$image = new ImageDownloader("images/");
$downloadedImage = $image->getImage("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
```